# Increasing the speed of a ball in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, motion

What I'm trying to do is simply make a ball rebound from a wall. Everything works OK, except the fact I want to be able to increase the speed of movement. Literally, the speed is how much 'x-value' is added (measured in px) to the ball's current position. The thing is, when I'm increasing the `var speed`, the ball floats out of the bounds, because the rebounding is checked by  the difference between the bound and the current position of the ball.

--------------------------------------update-----------------------------------------

I've used the technique suggested by Mekka, but still did something wrong.The ball doesn't float outside anymore, yet something "pushes it out" of the bounds for several pixels/"doesn't let the ball float several more pixels to reach the bounds".

My new code looks like this:

```
 // the bounds-describing object
var border={ 
    X:[8,302], // left and right borders in px 
    Y:[8,302], // top and bottom borders in px         
    indX:1, //border index for array Х 
    indY:0, //border index for array Y
    changeInd:function(n){return this[n] = +!this[n]; } // function to change the index
};


   if($("#ball").position().left + speed > border.X[1] || $("#ball").position().left + speed < border.X[0]){

                var distX = "+=" + (border.X[border.indX] - $("#ball").position().left);
                var distY = "-=" + ((border.X[border.indX] - $("#ball").position().left) * k);   

                $("#ball").css("left", distX);
                $("#ball").css("top", distY);

                border.changeInd("indX");
                speed = -speed;                    
   }

   if($("#ball").position().top + k > border.Y[1] || $("#ball").position().top + k < border.Y[0]){

                var distX = "+=" + ((border.Y[border.indY] - $("#ball").position().top) / k);
                var distY = "+=" + (border.Y[border.indY] - $("#ball").position().top);   

                $("#ball").css("left", distX);
                $("#ball").css("top", distY);

                border.changeInd("indY");

                k = -k;

    }
```

Another problem is that my code's math is incorrect sometimes, the reason of which I absolutely can't figure out. To test it, try 45 degrees with different speed.
The question is: how can I improve the 'collision-checking' process or even apply some other technique  to do this? 
the whole code can be found here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/au99f/16/

Answer (score 3):

You're very close! The answer is actually hinted at in your question. You're currently using the absolute value of the distance to the boundary to determine when to change direction. This defines a "magic zone" where the ball can change direction that is about 6 pixels wide (given your speed of 3). When you increase speed to something higher (like 10), you could jump right over this magic zone.

A better way to do this would be to test if the next jump would put the ball completely outside the bounds. So this check is not based on a constant (like 3) but on the speed of the ball itself. You can also see how much the ball would have travelled out of bounds to determine how far to move the ball in the opposite direction. In other words, if your speed is 10, and the ball is 3 pixels from the right edge on step 8, then on step 9, the ball would be 7 pixels from the right edge, traveling left. Be wary of edge cases (ball could land exactly on bounds).